# What are some ways to have fun with a large amount of data? (ie, the Twitter, del.icio.us etc. APIs)

Tags: twitter, statistics, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

Twitter, Google, Amazon, del.icio.us etc. all give you a lot of data to play with, all for free. There's also a lot of textual data available through initiatives like Project Gutenberg. And that, it seems, is just the tip of the iceberg.

I have been wondering how you could use this data for fun. I'm a first year IT student, so I have no knowledge of statistics, machine learning, collaborative filtering etc. My interest in this area was piqued by the book *Programming Collective Intelligence* by Toby Segaran, and now I want to take a deeper look at what you can do with data. I don't know where to start. Any ideas?

I have also been pondering whether I should go and buy something like *Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming*. Is it worth the trip across the city?

Comment: Amazon sells books :) why travel across the city?

Comment: Doesn't sell books in India :(

Answer (score 6):

Try firing books in different styles  from Guttenberg  through a Markov Chain generator - there's one in Perl [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=55851) to get you started.

Comment: Beat me to it. Markov machines are great fun :)

Comment: Post the results to a Twitter account through its API and see how many followers you can get based on your machine generated Tweets.

Comment: I like it! But most twits seem to be poorly programmed AIs anyway. I have grave doubts about their ability to pass the Turing Test.

Comment: Well, you won't pass the Turing Test, but you could still have some fun by seeing how many "social media entrepreneurs" you can get to follow your nonsensical bot.  What if instead of using Project Gutenberg you just used other Tweets to train your bot?

Answer (score 3):

Visualizations, do them, share them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some of that data to make money (if you're really good!)
http://www.netflixprize.com/ Netflix has made available an anonymized dataset, and are asking for better algorithms to predict customer choices.

Comment: Yeah I was going to suggest this. I am working on this right now.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with Python try playing around with the [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/).  It has tons of libraries for text mining and even machine learning in general.  Try working your way through [nltk book](http://www.nltk.org/book).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start off with a easy AI problem, you might try clustering.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_clustering

You could use it to group flickr images together by tag or something cool like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make puzzles like hangman games. Or a mashup or try Yahoo pipes to join information.

Answer (score 0):

Predict future stockmarket trends from the data.  Profit!